# Android soft keyboard on EditText do not work properly on second touch

Tags: android, android-listview, android-softkeyboard, android-dialog

My problem consistis in the second time the keyboard shows up on the SAME EditText.

I have many EditTexts inside a ListView, inside a Dialog, and the keyboard is set to ADJUST PAN. So far it is working fine, but when my list is bigger than the device screen and the EditText from last row is touched in first time the keyboard shows up and cover the layout correctly. But if I hide the keyboard from it native button to hide and click on the same EditText again the keyboard shows up and cover the layout and the Edittext, instead of covering and pushing to keep showing the EditText as the first time.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: i just solve this problem, here you can see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35884527/5023004