# adjustpan not work in expandablelistview when click second time for the same edittext

Tags: android

first time,click an edittext in expandablelistview,the whole layout scrolled ,and user can see edittext. then click softkeyboard finish to collapse softkeyboard and click this edittext second time ,softkeyboard  show, but the whole layout not scrolled, and user cannot see edittext. I find this in listview ,too.I searched for a long time and some one says it is an anroid bug?
 Is there any replacement?

Answer (score 0):

By many days spent,I found a solution. It is a hack.

1. put you edittext wrapped in linearlayout.
2. detect softkeyboard show by visiable layout change.

   ```
    public final void setKeyboardListener(final OnKeyboardVisibilityListener listener) {

    final View activityRootView = getWindow().getDecorView()
       .findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver()
       .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

         private final Rect r = new Rect();
         private boolean wasOpened;

         @Override
         public void onGlobalLayout() {
           activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

           int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight()
               - (r.bottom - r.top);
           boolean isOpen = heightDiff > 100;

           if (isOpen == wasOpened) {
             return;
           }

           wasOpened = isOpen;
           listener.onVisibilityChanged(isOpen);
         }
       });
      }

     public interface OnKeyboardVisibilityListener {

      void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible);
       }
   ```
3. when the softkeyboard show,pick up a textview in listview item or expandablelistview child item. then set it text for any thing, the whole view scrolled as normal! code like this:

   ```
   activity.setKeyboardListener(new OnKeyboardVisibilityListener() {
     @Override
   public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
   if (visible) {
     Message message = new Message();
     message.what = 999;
     handler.sendMessage(message);
     }
    }
   });
   private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
   if (msg.what == 999) {
     if (mDataMap.size() > 0) {
     for (int i = 0; i < expandablelistview.getChildCount(); i++) {
       View v = expandablelistview.getChildAt(i);
       TextView tvCannotSee = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_cannot_see );
       if (tvCannotSee != null) {
         //this is the key hack to make adjuspan work! and scroll the whole view up as normal
         tvCannotSee.setText("this is an android bug");
         return;
         }
       }
      }
      return;
     }
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    }
   };
   ```
4. this textview show invisble to user for proper purpose.if it is a expandablelistview and the edittext in childitem,the textview update must be in a childitem.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue, but after googling the issue for some time i ended up the problem as below.

1) Add             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" tag inside activity of manifest file

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|layoutDirection|screenLayout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"></activity>
```

2) add  android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants" attribute to your expandable listview as below.

```
    <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textDate"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_meium"
                android:groupIndicator="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Comment: no this cannot work,click this edittext second time ,softkeyboard show, but the whole layout not scrolled, and user cannot see edittext. do u make this ok?